# Why does normalization improve my decision tree performances?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-trees, normalization

I have a regression problem for which I have to try several models, so I normalized my data and then tried to use a decision tree regressor (from sklearn.tree) and I noticed very good results (explained variance higher than 0.999). After some research I found out that for decision tree normalization is irrelevant, so I tried to skip the normalization process and explained variance went down (in several tries it stays between -0.006 and 0.006). Is it possible than normalization affects the decision tree performances or maybe there is some coding issue or something like that?

Comment: are you sure you are training/evaluating in the same data?  What kind of normalization are you using?

Comment: I was but I'm not sure anymore, I tried to run everything from the start and now I have bad results in both cases, which is bad, but at least it makes sense

Comment: in order for the community to be able to help you, you might want to do some reproducible code.

Comment: In your case, add a random seed, see if it solves the problem

Comment: It is possible there is some error in code possibly in the normalisation routine

Comment: A website says - what’s the difference between normalization and standardization?
 There are two of the most commonly used feature scaling techniques in machine learning but a level of ambiguity exists in their understanding. When should you use which technique?

Comment: what is your regression  problem? details?